# Explain: True or False: If $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{dy/dx}=0$, then tangent line to the curve $y = f(x)$ is horizontal.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions, maxima-minima, tangent-line

**Explain:** True or False: If $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{dy/dx}=0$, then tangent line to the curve $y = f(x)$ is horizontal.

The answer is false. But I don't know why. Here's my train of thought and would love for someone to guide me:

- If (the inverse of) $\frac{1}{\Delta y/\Delta x} = 0$, then there must be a zero in the non-inverse derivative $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.
- If this is true, that means there's a maximum or minimum value to the curve.
- Which means for the function, there'd be a part of the curve that will be $0$

However they never stated where the tangent line is drawn, so there's a possibility that it can be true?

Would like to understand this and it'd be great if you can me identify my knowledge gap?

Comment: What they want you to realize is this: when the tangent line to a curve y = f(x) is horizontal in some point (x0, y0), then dy/dx = 0 in that point. In the exercise they take the reciprocal (= dx/dy), which is nonsense. The intention of the exercise is that you quickly recognize that the statement is FALSE.

Comment: $dx/dy=cotA$ where $A$ is angle made by tangent line with positive x-axis therefore $cotA=0$ and hence $A=\pi/2$ meaning a vertical line rather than horizontal

Comment: The question in itself should never pass a board to begin with because it's lacking proper detail. Are we talking about the value of the derivative at some given fixed point? This is not clear and that is troubling...

Comment: Actually, it is merely a trick question.  You confused $(dx/dy)$ with $(dy/dx)$. If the question has asserted that the tangent line is **vertical**, then, in my opinion, the assertion would have been true, as long as the $$ = \frac{1}{dy/dx} ~~\text{nonsense}$$ is removed from the problem.

Comment: So... it's just a bad question..?

Comment: The question does not have to be a bad question by intention. However the way it has been worded, in those exact words, it should not appear on a paper